# Calling a web method from jquery ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am trying to call a web method from jquery, but I cannot get it to work. Please note that I have tried to many of the suggestions in other answers, but nothing has worked so far.

When I call the method from the Page_Load, it works correctly. Its only when I call from .ajax() that it fails. I am getting an "internal server error" and when I debug in the browser, I get a "failed to load resource".

For the life of me, I cannot figure out what is wrong. Any help is appreciated.

My ASP code:

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
        var iipServ = "http://localhost/fcgi-bin/iipsrv.fcgi";
        var imgDir = String($("#<%= hfImageDir.ClientID %>").val());
        var objData = String($("#<%= hfObjectData.ClientID %>").val());
        var docid = $.url(window.location).param('doc');


        $('#diva-viewer').diva({
            iipServerURL: iipServ,
            objectData: objData,
            imageDir: imgDir,
            tileFadeSpeed: 100,
            fixedHeightGrid: true,
            enableAutoTitle: false,
            enableFullscreen: false,
            contained: true,
            enableAutoHeight: true,
            enableAutoWidth: true,
            enableDownload: true,
            zoomLevel: 2
        });

        Events.subscribe("VisiblePageDidChange", function (pagenumber, fn) {

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "Viewer.aspx/GetTest",
                datatype: "json",       
                data: {docID: JSON.stringify(docid), 
                       pageNumber: JSON.stringify(pagenumber)},
                success: function (response) {

                    alert("YAY!!");
                    alert(response.d);
                    $("#page-data").html(response.d);

                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    alert("responseText=" + xhr.responseText + 
                      "\n textStatus=" + status + "\n errorThrown=" + error);
                }                  
            });
        });
    });
```

And from my code behind page, Viewer.aspx.cs:

```
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public static String GetTest(string docID, string pageNumber)
    {
        String test = "";
        try
        {
            test = "docID = " + docID + " pageNumber = " + pageNumber;
            var ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            Show(ser.Serialize(test));

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Log the exception.
            ArchiveViewer.Logic.ExceptionUtility.LogException(ex, 
                 "GetPages in Viewer.aspx.cs");

        }
        return test;
    }
```

Comment: @KhanhTO Wouldn't he need the `contentType` in there? And `dataType` only affects what comes back from the server - the error in this case happens earlier - though I do acknowledge that it should be changed all the same.

Comment: Question re: the contentType? I will be passing JSON data back (this is not my real function). When should I use 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'?

Comment: @KhanhTO Looking at this link: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/04/04/json-hijacking-and-how-asp-net-ajax-1-0-mitigates-these-attacks.aspx it seems as though WebMethods require the content type to be set to `application/json`.

Comment: @nick_w: thanks, I was not sure. That why I posted as a comment

Comment: @Tums See the edit to me answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a couple of problems with your code as it is.

Firstly, you currently pass the data to `$.ajax` like this:

```
data: {docID: JSON.stringify(docid),
    pageNumber: JSON.stringify(pagenumber)},
```

What worked for me was changing it to this:

```
data: JSON.stringify({docID: docid,
    pageNumber: pagenumber}),
```

Without that change, jQuery was sending the data to the server as `docId=10&pageNumber=20` which was causing JSON deserialization issues on the server-side.

Secondly, you have `datatype: "json"`. It should be `dataType: "json",` - note the capital `T`. That said, jQuery will guess what this should be based on what comes back from the server, which in this case is always sending back JSON, but still.

**Edit:**

In jQuery `ajax`, the `contentType` property sets the `Content-Type` HTTP header on the request, indicating the MIME-type of the request body.

The `dataType` property sets the `Accept` header on the request, indicating the MIME-types of the response that are acceptable.

In your case, `WebMethods` require the Content-Type to be `application/json`, so setting `contentType` as you are is correct.

If you want to, you can also set the `dataType` to be `json`. It isn't really necessary in this case as jQuery will guess what this should be based on the `Content-Type` header of the response. As your Web Method is configured to always return JSON, this header should always end up as `application/json; charset=utf-8`, meaning that jQuery should always make the correct guess.

Comment: I was indeed passing the data incorrectly. I tried so many variants of that line from looking at many examples, but I must have missed that one (or typed it incorrectly). Thank you!